# Cypress: verify content of xlsx file generated on frontend in headless mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, testing, cypress

We are using npm [`xlsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to generate xlsx document containing data presented in React view. We want to implement Cypress UI test which verifies that data are exported correctly by downloading generated file, opening it and asserting its content. Test is being executed within our CI pipeline - meaning it runs in headless mode (and using `electron` browser).

This is how we generate data:

```
import XLSX from "xlsx";

export function createXlsx(data, sheetName, fileName) {
  const workSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);

  const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, sheetName);

  XLSX.writeFile(workBook, fileName);
}
```

When user clicks "Export" button, data are passed to `createXlsx` method and user is prompted with save dialog.

For Cypress part, we have followed [tutorial](https://dev.to/viveknayyar/e2e-testing-of-excel-downloads-with-cypress-21fb)*, having following setup in `plugins/index.js`:

```
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    const downloadDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), config.env.testDownloadsDirectory);

    if (browser.family === 'chromium') {
      if (launchOptions.preferences.default) {
        launchOptions.preferences.default['download'] = { default_directory: downloadDirectory };
      }
    }

    return launchOptions;
  });

  on('task', {
    parseXlsx({ filePath }) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const workBook = xlsx.readFile(filePath);
          const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workBook.Sheets.Data);
          resolve(data);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

... and test:

```
    ...

    cy.get('button[data-cy="export"]').click();

    cy.readFile(filePath, 'binary', { log: true, timeout: 5000 })
      .should('exist');

    cy.task('parseXlsx', { filePath })
      .then(data => {
        // assertions here
      });

    ...
```

All this works nicely when running locally with `--headed --browser chrome` - file is saved, then loaded and asserted.

It does not work when executing tests `--headless` (* this *is* mentioned in comments below tutorial).

Since I'm relatively new to JavaScript/React, I'm wondering if this could be done somehow. Firstly, I don't really understand how `XLSX.writeFile(...)` makes browser to open save dialog and if it would be possible to hook into it.

Another idea I had was to create regular React endpoint (having own URI, e.g. `/#/xlsx-export`) which would generate the file, so I could try to call `http.get(...)` from registered Cypress task event handler, but since it is still React app, I'm suspecting it won't make any difference. (This approach also prevents me from doing data manipulation before I press export button)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I need access a downloaded file and run tests on it. --headed mode works fine, though in --headless mode the file does not download (no errors though). I would need --headless mode to work so I can integrate cypress into our gitlab pipeline. Anyone have any updates on this issue?